# Java Increase Rectangle Thickness

Tags: java, user-interface, graphics

How do I increase the thickness of the rectangle when using `g.drawRect`? I want the blue rectangle to have a thick line.

This is my code -

```
if(selectedApartment == 0)
 {
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.fillRect (150, 120,aptWidth, aptHeight);
    **g.setColor(Color.blue);
    g.drawRect(150, 120, aptWidth, aptHeight);**
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.setFont(new Font("BoldFont",Font.BOLD,14));
    g.drawString("1", 150+15, 120+25);
 }
    else if (selectedApartment != 0)
     {
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillRect (150, 120,aptWidth, aptHeight);
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawRect(150, 120, aptWidth, aptHeight);
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.setFont(new Font("BoldFont",Font.BOLD,14));
        g.drawString("1", 150+15, 120+25);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use setStroke to set a stroke of the Graphics2D object.

Here's an example of this code segment in a program:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import javax.swing.*;

public class FrameTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame jf = new JFrame("Demo");
        Container cp = jf.getContentPane();
        cp.add(new JComponent() {
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
                g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(10));
                g2.draw(new Line2D.Float(30, 20, 80, 90));
            }
        });
        jf.setSize(300, 200);
        jf.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

(Note that the setStroke method is not available in the Graphics object. You have to cast it to a Graphics2D object.)